# How to support two conditions in the group by clause (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three table TableA, TableB, TableC  they all are linked by id.  Table A has logTime and tableB has detectionTime and TableC has emptId.

For each empId I want
    1. count of logTime when no detectionTime found in tableB
    2.  average of logTime and detectionTime difference if detectionTime found.

I have written this query that gets the average when detectionTime found but not sure how to get data when detectionTime not found

```
select det.empid  ,average(det.blocked_time) 
FROM (SELECT c.emplid as empid, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ( a.detectionTime - b.logTime )) as blocked_time
        ## inner and join condition here
  ) As det group by det.emplid where dat.blocked_time>0
```

Here I got entry when blocked_time>0 average and other stats.

How to get count of blocked_time for each empId when blocked_time is 0

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As no sample data is shared, so an (assumed) option could be to use `left join` and `coalesce` in inner query to convert `NULL` values for `detectionTime` to `0` and then use conditional aggregation in outer query as below.

```
select det.empid  ,
       avg(case when detectionTime  > 0 then det.blocked_time end) as avgBlockedTime, 
       sum(case when detectionTime =  0 then 0 else 1 end) as logTimeCount
FROM (SELECT c.emplid as empid, 
      EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ( a.detectionTime - b.logTime )) as blocked_time,
      coalesce(DetectionTime,0) as detectionTime
      ## left outer join and condition here
  ) As det 
group by det.empid
```

Comment: Thanks so much @zarruq for helping me solve this issue.  I want to know how to add this case statement to calculate median.  Currently  i am calling median using  TO_CHAR(((SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER by det.blocked_time)) 
             || ' second')::interval, 'HH24:MI:SS') MedianBlockedTime,

Comment: @Alchemist: Kindly ask another question. Someone will help you for sure with that also :-)

Answer (score 2):

First, a few comments:

- Your. SQL statement is syntactically incorrect. `WHERE` must come before `GROUP BY`.
- Your query seems to assume that `id` is a unique key for all three tables. Otherwise the same value could appear in the join result multiple times.

The expression you are looking for is

```
count(blocked_time) FILTER (WHERE blocked_time = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
select emptid,
sum(case when detectiontime is null then 1 else 0 end) as count,
average(case when detectiontime is not null then diff else 0 end) as avg
(
select a.*,b.detectiontime,c.emptid,a.logtime-b.detectiontime as diff
from
tablea a
left join
tableb b
on a.id = b.id
left join
tablec c
on a.id = c.id
)
group by emptid;
```

Let me know if you are looking for something else.

Comment: Thanks G.Arima.  I just want to know to add this case condition with median.  Median function that I am using is PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER by det.blocked_time)